# On Azure IOT Hub, Is it possible to create a device which acts an alias for an already deployed device?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

For Azure IOT Hub - I am working on a project where I would like to create some scripts based around the device name of an IOT device in the field. The device name already has details related to the location and device number of the location (which is what the script will pull).

Example H4C1F5Device3, where H4C1F5 is the postal code, and device 3 refers to the 3rd device in this location.

However due to a mixup in deployment, some devices don't match this naming convention and make scripting a little broken.

So my question is there a way to create an "alias"/dummy device in IOT hub with the correct name which can point to the previously deployed device with the "incorrect" name?

So far I have only looked at solutions in the Portal (no CLI, Node.js, etc.). I have tried making changes in the "Device Twins" page, but it does not accept changes when attempting to save.

Would appreciate any help on this. The Azure documentation is quite good, but I'm having trouble finding the solution to this exact query.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in Azure IoT Hub. You could create the new device IDs and reprovision your device with the new credentials.

It's also good practice not to store this kind of information in the device ID. You could use tags on the device twin (or desired properties if the device needs to know), unlike the device ID they are mutable.